# How to transfer a method from Array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

so what I am trying to do it transfer my Array methods that reverse my arrays and merge two others into ArrayLists. I have been able to do this with all other methods that I have, except for these two. I am getting an error from my reverse method that says unexpected type, required variable, found value. I am not sure what to do to fix it. Here are my working methods in my Array class:

```
/***        <<< CODE COMPLETE >>>
    * reverses the order of the elemets in the array 
    ***/
    public static void reverse(int[] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++)
        {
            int reverseOrder = a[i];
            a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
            a[a.length - 1 - i] = reverseOrder;
        }
    }

   /***        <<< CODE COMPLETE >>>
    * merges two sorted arrays into 1 new array, maintains the sorted order 
    ***/
    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) 
    {
        int[] merge = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (i < a.length && j < b.length)
        {
            if (a[i] < b[j])
            {
                merge[k++] = a[i++];
            }

            else        
            {
                merge[k++] = b[j++];
            }
        }

        while (i < a.length)
        {
            merge[k++] = a[i++];
        }


        while (j < b.length)  
        {
            merge[k++] = b[j++];
        }

        return merge;
    }
```

and here is what I have been trying to do in making these Array's into ArrayList's:

```
/***        <<< CODE NOT COMPLETE >>>
   * reverses the order of the elemets in the array 
   ***/
  public static void reverse(ArrayList <Integer> a)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < a.size()/2; i++)
       {
           int reverseOrder = a.get(i);
           a.get(i) = a.get(a.size() - 1 - i);
           a.get(a.size() - 1 - i) = reverseOrder;
       }
   } 

   /***        <<< CODE NOT COMPLETE >>>
   * merges two sorted arrays into 1 new array, maintains the sorted order 
   ***/
   public static ArrayList <Integer> merge (ArrayList <Integer> a, ArrayList <Integer> b) 
   {
       ArrayList <Integer> merge = new ArrayList <Integer> (a.size() + b.size());
       int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

       while (i < a.size() && j < b.size())
       {
            if (a.get(i) < b.get(j))
            {
                merge.get(k++) = a.get(i++);
            }

            else        
            {
                merge.get(k++) = b.get(j++);
            }
       }

       while (i < a.size())
       {
           merge.get(k++) = a.get(i++);
       }

       while (j < b.length)  
       {
           merge.get(k++) = b.get(i++);
       }

       return merge;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see here is using `.get()` on the left side. `.get()` gives you the thing at that index, but it's different from an array in that it doesn't allow you to set anything there.

For that, you need `set()`.

For example, your first method should have:

```
a.set(i, a.get(a.size() - 1 - i));
```

rather than:

```
a.get(i) = a.get(a.size() - 1 - i);
```

Here are the JavaDocs on the `set()` method if you want to read up on it a bit (it's quite straightforward). Basically with an array `arr[i]` gives you the value at `i`, but also allowed you to set the content at index `i`. For `ArrayList` those two operations are separate methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: Okay so that at least allowed me to compile with my reverse method. However, I am still experiencing some issues. For example, in the array I am reversing, it is printing the index locations of the first 3 integers, then the last 3 are the actual, correct integers. Peculiarly it returns false for order, which it is supposed to do. So the compiler recognizes it is not in order, however it only print out half the numbers. With my merge, it compiles, but in my main method, I do not know how to convert it to ArrayList so I can't see if the logic is right.

Comment: This is the array version of what I used to merge the arrays, but I'm not sure what to do to merge it with ArrayList being used: int merged[] = merge(num3,num4);
        print(merged);

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the main problem I see is that you have a lot of this code in your work:

```
merge.get(i) = a.get(j);
```

That effectively does nothing. The reason for this is that the `get` method of `ArrayList` instances only returns the current value at the index you passed in. You are not able to set the value at this index with this method, for that you must use the instance method `set`, like so:

```
merge.set(i, a.get(j));
```

Where i is the index that you want to set, and `a.get(j)` is the value you want to set that index to.

Comment: Okay so that at least allowed me to compile with my reverse method. However, I am still experiencing some issues. For example, in the array I am reversing, it is printing the index locations of the first 3 integers, then the last 3 are the actual, correct integers. Peculiarly it returns false for order, which it is supposed to do. So the compiler recognizes it is not in order, however it only print out half the numbers. With my merge, it compiles, but in my main method, I do not know how to convert it to ArrayList so I can't see if the logic is right.

Comment: This is the array version of what I used to merge the arrays, but I'm not sure what to do to merge it with ArrayList being used: int merged[] = merge(num3,num4); print(merged);

Comment: Can you add the code of printing the index locations?

Comment: This is what I am getting printed out: ---array example 1---
4, 5, 9, 7, 3, 4, 8, 
The largest value is: 9
The smallest value is: 3
In order: false

---array example 2---
24, 87, 96, 102, 874, 941, 
reverse order: 5, 4, 3, 96, 87, 24, 
In order: false

---array example 3---
2, 6, 8, 9, 
1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 
merged array: In order: true

Comment: As far as I can tell, in the reverse order, those are the index locations, then the last 3 integers. 941, 874, 102 should be where 5,4,3 are

Comment: Its supposed to only print the integers, not the index locations.